# You don't have permission to access /files/theme/icons on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've recently got an error on my site while trying to get Apaxy to work.
After a while I realized that the icons are not accessible. When I try to open them I get this error message:

#### Error

```
You don't have permission to access /files/theme/icons on this server.
```

This is a part of my apache2.conf (httpd.conf) and everything seems alright in it:

#### Code

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I tried everything I found on SO but it didn't work.
I'm not overriding the permissions with any .htaccess file.

I'm running Apache 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing permissions to read+execute.